# Prove transitivity in Fitch

Tags: logic, symbolic-logic, fitch

How to prove transitivity in Fitch.
Is it Ok?

```
| 1. a = b
| 2. b = c
| 3. c = c  =Intro
| 4. a = c  =Elim: 3, 2
| 5. b = c  =Elim: 4, 1
```

Comment: I made an edit adding some formatting. You may roll this back or continue editing. You can see the versions by clicking on the "edited" link. Welcome to this SE!

Comment: Line 3 is unneeded, and line 4 is where you should stop (and its by =Elim: 1,2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to get the proof as you presented it to work in the fitch-style proof checker I am using.

However, the following did work using equality elimination (=E).

[image]

The proof checker you are using may be different and the result could require other steps.

---

References

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

P. D. Magnus, Tim Button with additions by J. Robert Loftis remixed and revised by Aaron Thomas-Bolduc, Richard Zach, forallx Calgary Remix: An Introduction to Formal Logic, Winter 2018. http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/
Wikipedia, "Fitch notation" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitch_notation

Answer (score 0):

The = introduction rule is that: an entity will equal itself.

```
|_
|  c=c    = intro
```

This is a distraction.  You do not need it for your proof.

The = elimination rule is that: you may substitute an entity for an entity that it equals.

```
|  a=b
|_ F(b)
|  F(a)   = elim
```

Now this is just what you need.  Transitivity (of equality) is that: if a=b and b=c then a=c . Which is clearly substituting a for b in b=c.

```
|  a=b
|_ b=c
|  a=c    = elim
```

In full

```
|_
|  |_ (a=b)˄(b=c)
|  |  a=b             ˄ elim
|  |  b=c             ˄ elim
|  |  a=c             = elim
|  ((a=b)˄(b=c))→(a=c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the proof for transitivity of identity.

[image]